# Mirror binary tree in Prolog

Tags: recursion, prolog, binary-tree

What I have...

```
tree(nil).
tree(b(Left,_,Right)) :-
    tree(Left),
    tree(Right).

mirror(b(Left,Head,Right), NewTree) :-
    mirror(Left,NewLeft),
    mirror(Right,NewRight),
    NewTree = b(NewRight,Head,NewLeft).
```

What I'm querying...

```
mirror(b(nil,a,b(nil,b,nil)), Result).
```

Expected result

```
Result = b(b(nil,b,nil),a,nil).
```

The tree b(Left,Right,Head) is the first argument of mirror, NewTree is the goal. mirror(Left,NewLeft) recurses through the left side and yields the goal NewLeft, same for Right. NewTree is the tree b(NewRight,Head,NewLeft).

I'm not sure why this isn't working could someone please help.

Comment: You're missing the base case for `mirror/2`. What should NewTree be when the input tree is `nil`?

Comment: @Steven Should it be nil?

Comment: indeed. So just add a clause for that and your query will work.

Comment: @Steven Okay, I've only been doing Prolog for 2 days so bear with me... Is this correct 

`mirror(nil,NewTree) :-
 NewTree = nil.
mirror(b(Left,Head,Right), R) :-
 mirror(Left,NewLeft),
 mirror(Right,NewRight),
 R = b(NewRight,Head,NewLeft).`

Comment: @PabloH that's fine, but move your final clauses into the head: `mirror(nil, nil).` and `mirror(b(Left,Head,Right), b(NewRight,Head,NewLeft)) :- mirror(Left, NewLeft), mirror(Right, NewRight).`

Answer (score 1):

Based on your current code

```
tree(nil).
tree(b(Left,_,Right)) :-
    tree(Left),
    tree(Right).

mirror(b(Left,Head,Right), NewTree) :-
    mirror(Left,NewLeft),
    mirror(Right,NewRight),
    NewTree = b(NewRight,Head,NewLeft).
```

you are very close.

As noted in a comment by Steven

> You're missing the base case for mirror/2. What should NewTree be when the input tree is nil?

is very helpful.

Before getting to the full working predicate lets clear up a other things.
The predicate for tree is not needed.

```
tree(nil).
tree(b(Left,_,Right)) :-
    tree(Left),
    tree(Right).
```

I don't know if you are showing this to shows us that you know how a tree works or what but for others reading this predicate it is not needed for the answer.

That leaves only

```
mirror(b(Left,Head,Right), NewTree) :-
    mirror(Left,NewLeft),
    mirror(Right,NewRight),
    NewTree = b(NewRight,Head,NewLeft).
```

A standard style with using a variable that works like an input and output with several usages is for the starting one, append a 0, then for each succeeding use increase the appended number and for the result append nothing.

```
mirror(b(Left0,Head,Right0), NewTree) :-
    mirror(Left0,Left),
    mirror(Right0,Right),
    NewTree = b(Right,Head,Left).
```

Next [=/2](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=%3D/2) is just doing unification. This can be refactored as such

```
mirror(b(Left0,Head,Right0), b(Right,Head,Left)) :-
    mirror(Left0,Left),
    mirror(Right0,Right).
```

Now back to your problem

Since a tree is a recursive structure, it can be processed with with recursion. Predicates that work on recursive data structures need a base clause and a clause to do the recursion. You already have a clause to do the recursion but just need a base clause.

If you use the SWI-Prolog gui tracer on your code for the query

```
mirror(b(nil,a,b(nil,b,nil)), Result).
```

you will see

[image]

that when one of the branches is just `nil` there is no mirror/2 rule to handle this case.

Adding

```
mirror(nil,nil).
```

will solve your problem.

```
?- mirror(b(nil,a,b(nil,b,nil)), Result).
Result = b(b(nil, b, nil), a, nil).
```

The entire predicate.

```
mirror(nil,nil).

mirror(b(Left0,Head,Right0), b(Right,Head,Left)) :-
    mirror(Left0,Left),
    mirror(Right0,Right).
```